# How can I find the products that are between two price intervals ,

Tags: spring-boot

How can I find the products that are between two price intervals ,i use to retrieve the Products but i get the `Arrays` Empty , can someone Help Me ?

```
public List<Product>getAllProductBetween(int price1 , int price2){
                
                
                List<Product> product = new ArrayList<>();
                List<Product> prodretrieved = new ArrayList<>()  ;
                product = productRepository.findAll();
                //Product  productRang ;
                
                
                for(int i=0;i <product.size();i++) {
                    
                    if(price1 > product.get(i).getPrice() && price2 < product.get(i).getPrice()){
                        
                        
                    //productRang = product.get(i);
                         
                         prodretrieved.add(product.get(i));
                         
                }
                    }
                    
                
                return prodretrieved;
                
            }
        
}
```

############# My Controller ###########

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('READ')")

@RequestMapping("/{price1}/{price2}")

public List<Product> getproductbetween(@PathVariable int price1 ,@PathVariable int price2){

return this.productService.getAllProductBetween(price1, price2) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of `if` condition, use:

```
if(price1 < product.get(i).getPrice() && product.get(i).getPrice()< price2){
    prodretrieved.add(product.get(i));
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Zabihullah Alipour it works like charm :)